# lisp - error: no function definition: BUTLAST

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I am trying to use `butlast` but for some reason, I get this
error: no function definition: BUTLAST. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`butlast` does not exist in AutoLisp so that the error says there is such function is on point.

You can define it though

```
(defun butlast (lst)
  (reverse (cdr (reverse lst))))
```